# how to create regex to accept combination of alphabets, numbers and special characters but not single alphabet or number or special characters

Tags: php, regex

I want to create regex which will accept combination of alphabets, special characters,numbers but not only alphabets or special characters or numbers

For example :
It should accept

1. 1 Slice brown bread (wheat)
2. 1 Tbsp
3. 1/2 cup

But it should not accept

1. Slice brown bread
2. 1
3. @#%&%&*

This is what I have tried:

```
regex:/^(?![0-9]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9\s\-()\/ ]+$/'
```

This regex allow user to accept combination of alphabets, numbers and special characters but not only numbers.

Comment: Have You Tried Anything? If Yes, Please Paste Your Tried Code Too.

Comment: @NanaPartykar : regex:/^(?![0-9]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9\s\-()\/ ]+$/' this is what i have tried. This regex allow user to accept combination of alphabets, numbers and special characters but not only numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By chaining a few negative lookaheads to the regex, so it won't match when there's only 1 of the types + whitespaces on the same line.

```
$str = '1 Slice brown bread (wheat) 
1 Tbsp 
1/2 cup 
Slice brown bread 
1
@#%&%&*';

$re = '/^(?!\W+$)(?![\d\s]+$)(?![A-Za-z\s]+$).+$/m';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
var_dump($matches);
```

Btw, in the examples, all the acceptables seem to start with a digit, and have letters.
So with `$re = '/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])\d+.+$/m';`, to match lines that start with a number and have at least a letter, it would also only match the first 3 examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(\d+)(\/\d)?(\s\w+)+(\s\(\w+\))?
```

[Try it out here](http://myregexp.com?regex=%5E(%5Cd%2B)(%5C%2F%5Cd)%3F(%5Cs%5Cw%2B)%2B(%5Cs%5C(%5Cw%2B%5C))%3F&text=1%20Slice%20brown%20bread%20(wheat)%0D%0A1%20Tbsp%0D%0A1%2F2%20cup%0D%0ASlice%20brown%20bread%0D%0A1%0D%0A%40%23%25%26%25%26*%0D%0A1%20bread%20tomato%20(asdsad)%0D%0A1%2F3%20bread%20deta%20(asdsad)%0D%0A&flags=gm)